# Download iCloud video to the temporary directory

Tags: ios, download, icloud, phasset

I want to download PHAsset video from iCloud to the app's temporary directory. How to do it, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2):

This code should get you started:

```
 PHImageManager* manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    PHVideoRequestOptions* requestOptions = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
    requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    requestOptions.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError* error, BOOL* stop, NSDictionary* info) {
        NSLog(@"cacheAsset: %f", progress);
    };
    [manager requestExportSessionForVideo:inAsset
                                  options:requestOptions
                             exportPreset:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough resultHandler:^(AVAssetExportSession* exportSession, NSDictionary* info) {
                                 exportSession.outputURL = url;
                                 exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
                                 [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                                     // Do something here with the result. Make sure to check the info dictionary for additional status.
                                 }];
                             }];
```

Comment: Thanks for this! We'd been using the requestAsset version and it *mostly* worked but there were issues with some icloud videos and shared icloud videos would often fail completely.